# $a+c$ is a root of $p(x)$ iff $a$ is a root of $p(x+c)$; $ca$ is a root of $p(x)$ iff $a$ is a root of $p(cx)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, roots

> $a+c$ is a root of $p(x)$ iff $a$ is a root of $p(x+c)$; $ca$ is a root of $p(x)$ iff $a$ is a root of $p(cx)$.

I know that $c$ is a zero of $p$ if and only if $(x − c)$ is a factor of $p(x)$. If $(x − c)$ is a factor of $p(x)$, this means $p(x) = (x − c) q(x)$ where $p(c)=0$. So $p(x+c)=(x-(x+c))q(x)=q(x)\cdot c$. Where $a$ needs to be a root of $q(x)$ I am assuming? Am I on the right track?

Comment: You are overthinking it.  Just substitute.  For instance, let $q(x)=p(x+c)$.  then $q(a)=p(a+c)$.  Thus one side is $0$ iff the other side is $0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asserting that $a+c$ is a root of $p(x)$ *means* that $p(a+c)=0$. And asserting that $a$ is a root of $p(x+c)$ also *means* that $p(a+c)=0$. So, the assertions are equivalente.

Can you do the same thing to prove the other equivalence?

Comment: So if $ca$ is a root of $p(x)$ then $p(ca)=0$ and if $a$ is a root of $p(cx)$ then $p(ca)=0$, and since $ca$ is a root for $p(x)$ then  $p(ca)=0$

Comment: @KMath No. Asserting that $ca$ is a root of $p(x)$ does **not** mean that $p(ca)=0$.

Comment: I apologize I hit enter before proofreading and then tried again

Comment: @KMath You are writing that in terms of “if … then”, which is innapropriate, since you want to prove equivalences.

Comment: Would it be better as "Supposing $ca$ is a root of $p(x)$ means $p(ca)=0$. Similarly supposing $a$ is a root of $p(cx)$ means $p(ca)=0$ since $ca$ is a root for $p(x)$. Thus proving equivalence."?

Comment: @KMath Delete the “since $ca$ is a root for $p(x)$” part and it will be fine.